# Negative number comparison with is operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain to me why in Python 15 `is` 15 but -15 `is not` -15? Does that make any sense?

```
In [1]: -15 is -15
Out[1]: False

In [2]: 15 is 15
Out[2]: True
```

It looks like -15 is an instance of something.

Comment: A small integer cache is the gist of it, also in play (at other instances), peep-hole optimizer. In short, these are implementation details that shouldn't really concern you.

Comment: is is the identity equality operator (functioning like id(a) == id(b)); it's just that two equal numbers aren't necessarily the same object.  Instead of using "is" try to check with "==" ;)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html 

@Marcosmdm you're not helping ;)

Comment: Exactly, the C-API does mention this :-)

Comment: The funny thing is that "foo" is "foo"... it's totally counter intuitive.